Is it possible to get the incoming call number in ionic capacitor?
I'm trying to get the incoming call number by using capacitor in ionic native. I used the code from this https://github.com/313hemant313/capacitor-plugin-incoming-call but the incoming call number not returning. Can anyone help that how to get the incoming call number in ionic capacitor?
